# Does がち mean "in excess"?

Tags: meaning

I have been reading a daily article during 朝礼.

One of the sentence used the word がち. The sample sentence is:

> 長所{ちょうしょ}は見逃{みのが}してしまいがちです。
>
> Abundant of misses.

I tried to ask my colleague about the meaning of がち and they said it means [in excess]. For example if used with しまいがちです it means a lot of misses?

But when I try to look at [alc.co.jp](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A1%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99&ref=sa) for examples. There were some with no しまいがち pattern.
For example:

> 飛行機や列車の中で『にわか講習会』が始まりがちです。

What does がち mean this time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In all of your examples, it means "likely to, tend to". It does not mean "excess".

> 長所は見逃してしまいがちです
> 'Pros tend to be (unwillingly) overlooked.'
>
> 飛行機や列車の中で『にわか講習会』が始まりがちです
> 'In airplanes or trains, **"pseudo-workshops" are likely to start**.'　  (Interpretation a)
> 'In airplanes or trains, "pseudo-workshops" are likely to **start**, (not likely to end).'　  (Interpretation b)
> '"Pseudo-workshops" are likely to start **within airplanes or trains**, (not elsewhere).'　  (Interpretation c)
> '"Pseudo-workshops" are likely to start **within** airplanes or trains, (not in front them or behind them, etc.).'　  (Interpretation d)
> '"Pseudo-workshops" are likely to start within **airplanes or trains**, (not within busses or cars, etc.).'　  (Interpretation e)
> 'In airplanes or trains, **"pseudo-workshops"** are likely to start, (not dance parties). 　(interpretation f)

Comment: With so many interpretations, is there one that is most frequently adopted? (I.e. feels most natural and it takes precedence over other interpretations)

Comment: @Flaw The context determines it. It is not particular to Japanese. The multiple interpretations that I gave to the second sentence only differ with what the focus of `がち` is.  Whatever you feel about the difference in frequency of the English translations holds for the interpretation of the Japanese sentence. In most cases, probably interpretation a is natural.

Comment: Ah I get what you mean (my rather English-centric brain had some difficulty understanding). I guess the type of sentence is disambiguated depending on where stress is given in the sentence much like in English as well?

Comment: @Flaw Yes. That's right. Stress in only a phonological manifestation (in English) of the focus, which is the real thing. In Japanese, the focus manifests as pitch (and pause) rather than stress.

Comment: Aren't these multiple interpretations beside the point? They don't have much to do with がち. There would be similar parallel interpretations if you replaced 始まりがちです with 始まります.

Comment: @dainichi You are right about the ambiguity of `始まります`, but that is optional. It only appears when you put sentential accents on certain positions. The point of my answer is that `がち` necessarily accompanies a focus. Since the construction introduces the notion of comparison (i.e., what is more likely than what), it requires a *reference set* of propositions. A focus is a requirement for this construction.

Comment: I've been taught it normally expresses a bad tendency. (By which I mean, 太郎さんはおいしい料理を作りがちだ would sound strange.) Is that correct? If so, it might be a step towards explaining the reasoning behind the "excess" translation.

Comment: @Amadan That is right. But I don't know how that connects to "excess".

Comment: @sawa: "見逃してしまいがち" -> "prone to mistakes" -> "makes a lot of mistakes (and it's a bad thing)" -> "makes *too many* mistakes" -> "excess". Not straightforward, but somewhat understandable. People who are not used to explaining language nuances can often have very nebulous (and wrong) word definitions.

Comment: @Amadan There is big gap from "prone to mistakes" to "makes a lot of mistakes" although I kind of understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

I think your friends might have misunderstood your question and thought you were asking about the slang term ガチ http://zokugo-dict.com/06ka/gachi.htm, which I believe originally came from the sumo lingo word がちんこ勝負 which means 'a serious match'.

This word has recently become quite popular among younger speakers to refer to not only being serious about something, but also with a meaning/usage similar to `マジで(？)`, namely `ガチで(？)`. Both are similar to English "Seriously!(?)".

Comment: That may be the case, but then, the question is, why they answered that it means "excess". Perhaps, they even didn't know the slang term you mention.